# LINQ to separate column value of a row to different rows in .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Consider  i have a datatable retrieved from oracle database in the following format

```
SNo.  |      Product                      |  Cost
-------------------------------------------------
1     |      colgate,closeup,pepsodent    |  50
2     |      rin,surf                     |  100
```

I need to change this into the following format using linq.Need to separate the product column with the help of comma by keeping the other columns same.

```
SNo.  |        Product      |   Cost
-------------------------------------
1     |        colgate      |    50
1     |        closeup      |    50
1     |        pepsodent    |    50
2     |        rin          |    100
2     |        surf         |    100
```

Comment: Could you separate your columns using | ? It seems difficult to understand your table structure.

Comment: the products seem like they are group by the cost??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this:

```
List<Product> uncompressedList = compressedProducts
    .SelectMany(singleProduct => singleProduct.ProductName
                                    .Split(',')
                                    .Select(singleProductName => new Product 
                                    { 
                                        SNo = singleProduct.SNo, 
                                        ProductName = singleProductName, 
                                        Cost = singleProduct.Cost 
                                    }))
    .ToList();
```

EDIT:

Product class is defined as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public Int32 SNo { get; set; }
    public String ProductName { get; set; }
    public Int32 Cost { get; set; }
}
```

and *compressedProducts* is just the initial list of products from your first example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Justyna but can u tell me what is "Product" and "compressedProducts" in "List<Product> uncompressedList = compressedProducts.Select......." statement.

Comment: Oh sorry, I probably should have provided you with some additional info. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: hi Justyna look the two comments in sequence,please help me in this i created a datatable and added the values for that like......DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 dt.Columns.Add("SNo", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(int)); 
 
 dt.Rows.Add(1, "colgate,closeup,pepsodent",50 );
 dt.Rows.Add(2, "rin,surf",100);

Comment: var dataRows =new List<DataRow>();
    List<DataRow> uncompressedList = rows
    .SelectMany(singleProduct => singleProduct["Product"].ToString()
                                    .Split(',')                       
                                    .Select(singleProductName => new DataRow
                        { SNo = singleProduct["SNo"], ProductName = singleProductName,Cost =singleProduct["Cost"] })).ToList();     I am getting error inside the "Select(singleProductName => new DataRow{ }" can u look into it and tell me the error pls Justyna pls.

Comment: You basically cannot create a DataRow instance like this. Instead of using "new DataRow{..." use, for example, a modelling class *Product* I wrote.

Comment: I tried that Product class ,its working fine Justyna..But my requirement is to work on the data table only not class.

Comment: Oh, I completely didn't realize that you don't have this table modelled somewhere :) Please take a look here for your solution: http://pastebin.com/mSHyEeNZ However, I think you're asking for trouble operating purely on DataRows. By the way, please use a fresh instance of a DataTable not to append to the first one when selecting (I'm talking about the *dt* in my query).

Comment: My pleasure. Feel free to accept my answer whenever you have a chance. And by the way, my name is Piotr :) Justyna is my surname.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is not a single-line Linq statement but, try this.

```
var output = new List<Product>();

foreach (var p in SqlResult)
{
    var products = p.Product.Split(',');
    output.AddRange(products.Select(product => new Product { SNo = p.SNo, ProductName = product, Cost = p.Cost }));
}
```

By-the-way, SqlResult is your results set from the database.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work from my limited testing...

```
var test = p1.Product.Split(',').Select(p => new { product = p }).Select(r => new { p1.SNo, r.product, p1.Cost, })
```

This is only for a single line, but can easily be explanded to include mutiple lines....

Answer (score 0):

I would favour a simple foreach because it is known than LINQ is slower that regular looping statements, but if you really want to go that path you could use something like which to you, maybe be easier to read:

**Given**

```
    class ProductOracle
    {
        public int SNo { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    }

    class ProductEntity
    {
        public int SNo { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    }
```

**Execution**

```
    var entities = new List<ProductOracle>
    {
        new ProductOracle{SNo=1,Product="colgate,closeup,pepsodent", Cost=50},
        new ProductOracle{SNo=2,Product="rin,surf", Cost=100}
    };
```

*With*

```
    var products = new List<ProductEntity>();

    entities.ForEach(element =>
    {
        element.Product.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(product =>
        {
            products.Add(new ProductEntity { SNo = element.SNo, Product = product, Cost = element.Cost });
        });
    });
```

*Or*

```
    var products = entities.SelectMany(element =>
        {
            var ProductEntities = new List<ProductEntity>();

            element.Product.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(product =>
            {
                ProductEntities.Add(new ProductEntity { SNo = element.SNo, Product = product, Cost = element.Cost });
            });

            return ProductEntities;
        });
```