# Separating the column values of DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Consider i have a DataTable dt retrieved from oracle database in the following format

```
Eno   |      EHobbies                     |  Esal
-------------------------------------------------
1     |      Cricket,Tennis,Carroms       |  500
2     |      Cricket,Volley               |  1000

//Datatable for above table
DataTable dt = new DataTable("EmployeeTable");
dt.Columns.Add("Eno", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("EHobbies", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Esal", typeof(int));    

dt.Rows.Add(1, "Cricket,Tennis,Carroms",500 );
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Cricket,Volley",1000);
```

I need to change this into the following format using linq on the DataTable dt .Need to separate the product column with the help of comma by keeping the other columns same.

```
Eno   |        EHobbies     |   Esal
-------------------------------------
1     |        Cricket      |    500
1     |        Tennis       |    500
1     |        Carroms      |    500
2     |        Cricket      |    1000
2     |        Volleyball   |    1000
```

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354037/linq-to-separate-column-value-of-a-row-to-different-rows-in-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would work:

```
var newRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .SelectMany(r => r.Field<string>("EHobbies")
                                  .Split(',')
                                  .Select(x => new { No = r.Field<int>("Eno"),
                                                     Hobbies = x,
                                                     Sal = r.Field<int>("Esal") }
                                         )
                           );

DataTable result = new DataTable("EmployeeTable");
result.Columns.Add("Eno", typeof(int));
result.Columns.Add("EHobbies", typeof(string));
result.Columns.Add("Esal", typeof(int));

foreach(var newRow in newRows)
    result.Rows.Add(newRow.No, newRow.Hobbies, newRow.Sal);
```

Answer (score 1):

This also helps:

```
DataTable newDt = new DataTable();
newDt.Columns.Add("Eno", typeof(int));
newDt.Columns.Add("EHobbies", typeof(string));
newDt.Columns.Add("Esal", typeof(int));

dt.AsEnumerable().ToList()
                 .ForEach(row => row["EHobbies"].ToString().Split(',').ToList()
                 .ForEach(item => newDt.Rows.Add(row["Eno"], item, row["Esal"])));
```