# Split One Row into many based on splitting string in multiple cells

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Trying to split one row into many based on string in two cells. it is similar to the question
[LINQ to separate column value of a row to different rows in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354037/linq-to-separate-column-value-of-a-row-to-different-rows-in-net)
but i need to split based on Product & Cost Columns rather than product column only

| SNo. | Product | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | colgate,closeup,pepsodent | 50,100,150 |
| 2 | rin,surf | 100 |

into

| SNo. | Product | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | colgate | 50 |
| 1 | closeup | 100 |
| 1 | pepsodent | 150 |
| 2 | rin | 100 |
| 2 | surf | 100 |

I'm using Linq to Object with Entity Framework

Comment: What you have tried? Why it is EF? What is result, List of the same objects?

Comment: @ Svyatoslav Danyliv i'm trying to normalize the table from the first to the second by splitting the products and its relevant cost into separate rows

Comment: `Normalize table` it is mean that you want to create new table? Or update existing? It is one time operation?

Comment: @ Svyatoslav Danyliv I need to create new List of of same object based on second table using linq as per the answer in the link shown in the question but instead of splitting based on Product field only, i want to split based on Product and Cost fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Since you have not presented any model it can be inaccurate in names.

```cs
var loaded = ctx.Products.ToList();

var query = 
    from p in loaded
    from sp in p.Product.Split(',').Zip(p.Cost.Split(','), (p, c) => (p, c))
    select new 
    {
        Sno = p.Sno,
        Product = sp.p,
        Cost = sp.c
    };

var splitted = query.ToList();
```

Comment: That won't work; two `from`s is a cross product, which produces 11 rows not 5.

Comment: Ah, I see, will fix

Comment: Almost :) - `surf` doesn't show up in your answer because you didn't extend the `Cost` `Split` to match the `Product` `Split` (and there should be a version of `Zip` for that... but there isn't)

Comment: I got 2 errors "A local or parameter named 'p' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter" and " Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported "

Comment: The issue is resolved by installing System.ValueTuple package (Install-Package "System.ValueTuple")

Answer (score 1):

Using @SvyatoslavDanyliv naming, here is an answer:

```
var loaded = ctx.Products.ToList();

var query = 
    from p in loaded
    from sp in p.Product.Split(',').Zip(p.Cost.Split(','), (p, c) => (p, c))
    select new 
    {
        Sno = p.Sno,
        Product = sp.p,
        Cost = sp.c
    };

var splitted = query.ToList();
```

It feels a bit complicated to me. I would prefer using an extension method to create a variant of `Zip` that repeats the last element of a shorter sequence to match the longer sequence:

```
public static class EnumerableExt {
    public static IEnumerable<(T1 First,T2 Second)> ZipExtend<T1,T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> s1, IEnumerable<T2> s2) {
        var s1e = s1.GetEnumerator();
        var s2e = s2.GetEnumerator();

        T1 s1eLast = default;
        T2 s2eLast = default;
        bool has_s2 = false;
        if (s1e.MoveNext()) {
            do {
                s1eLast = s1e.Current;
                if (s2e.MoveNext()) {
                    s2eLast = s2e.Current;
                    has_s2 = true;
                }
                else if (!has_s2)
                    yield break;
                yield return (s1eLast, s2eLast);
            } while (s1e.MoveNext());
            if (has_s2)
                while (s2e.MoveNext())
                    yield return (s1eLast, s2e.Current);
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

Then the answer is:

```
var query = 
    from p in loaded
    from pr in p.Product.Split(',').ZipExtend(p.Cost.Split(','))
    select new 
    {
        Sno = p.Sno,
        Product = pr.First,
        Cost = pr.Second
    };

var splitted = query.ToList();
```